# Anchor tag onclick function in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have made a dynamic table using jquery,
Now I want to edit that table with a link,
I write onclick function like that:

```
var array = $.parseJSON(arr);
debugger
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var row = "<tr>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].ID + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].Name + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].FatherName + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].RollNo + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].Age + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].Phone + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + array[i].Address + "</td>"
    + "<td><a href='#' onclick='check()'>Edit</a></td>"
    + "<td><a href='#'>Delete</a></td>"
    + "</tr>"
    $("#table").append(row);
}
function hideStudents() {
    $("#students").hide();
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not definedonclick @ StudentManagement.aspx:1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BLLayer std = new BLLayer();
        list = std.GetAllStudents();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        //hfListData.Value = json;
        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        strScript.Append("var arr='");
        strScript.Append(json);
        strScript.Append("';");
        strScript.Append("</script>");

        ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;

        if (!script.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "Var"))
        {
            script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Var", strScript.ToString());
        }
```

I used this on page load to create array. And pass server side variable to client side by registering event.

Comment: I guess you don't have your `check()` function in the global scope.

Comment: show ur array so i can create a fiddle

Comment: In what scope have you defined the function `check`?

Comment: @Jai how can make check() function in global scope?

Comment: thank you it worked. when i used window.check .

Comment: I write this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just this. It will work: jsfiddle.net/sherali/W4Km8/6080

```
window.check = function() { alert("Goood"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/6b9yv1ht/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.qwe', function() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text());


});
```

I tried making an onclick event for each anchor by adding a class for each anchor.Please check.
[DOCU](http://api.jquery.com/on/)